# JavaFX DatePicker opens in wrong location with -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I was testing DatePicker from JavaFX in Java Swing application from this example: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/05/javafx-8-datepicker-swing-application.html

During the test I was having difficulties with position of DatePicker popup window which always showed on bad coordinates (not under button). The problem is VM argument "`-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0`". I'm running JavaFX 11.0.6 on UHD with Windows 150% scale.

Without VM argument:

[image]

With VM argument:
[image]
Code:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class FXDatePickerInSwingExampleOrig {

    private JFrame frame;
    private DatePicker inPicker;
    private static final String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy";

    public static void main(String... args) {

        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale","1.0");

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            new FXDatePickerInSwingExampleOrig().initAndShowGUI();
        });
    }

    private void initAndShowGUI() {

        frame = new JFrame("JavaFX DatePicker in Swing App");
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(new Point(400, 200));

        Platform.runLater(() -> {

            fxPanel.setScene(createScene());
        });

        frame.requestFocus();
    }

    private Scene createScene() {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        // Title
        Label title1 = new Label("Click the DatePicker button");
        VBox titleVb = new VBox();
        titleVb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        titleVb.getChildren().add(title1);

        // Input date picker
        Label inPickLabel = new Label("Input date:");
        inPicker = new DatePicker();
        inPicker.setPromptText(pattern);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        StringConverter<LocalDate> converter =
                new LocalDateStringConverter(formatter, null);
        inPicker.setConverter(converter);
        grid.add(inPickLabel, 0, 0);
        grid.add(inPicker, 1, 0);


        // Vbox and scene
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(titleVb, grid);

        return new Scene(vbox);
    }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong or is this bug in Java?
Thank you

Comment: does this happen only when mixing in Swing? If so, you might consider adding the swing tag

Comment: Good point. I have converted it to pure FX ("extends Application") and then "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0" have no effect - work fine. I have added "swing" tag.